# How do I get the exact IP address of my mongodb database?

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, hosting, cpanel

I am trying to deploy my node app to my Cpanel however the page times out with an error

```
503 Service unavailable
```

The website works on Heroku, ngrok and localhost however on my hosting service, it doesn't.
I found out that the issue was due to port 27017 not being open.
On discussing with my hosting providers, they said
"We can open the ports for you but our policy is to open non-standard ports to specific IP's for better security of the server. Is it possible to get the exact IP addresses of the database server you are trying to connect to."

So I'm not familiar with mongodb database having a specific IP address. What could they mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To connect to your db, your node app needs a URL something like this.

```
const url = 'mongodb://hostnameOfMongo.example.com:27017'
```

Your database's hostname is the stuff after `mongodb://` and before `:27017`.

Open up a shell (a command window) and type

```
  ping -n 1 hostnameOfMongo.example.com
```

or maybe

```
  ping -c 1 hostnameOfMongo.example.com
```

It should show you the IP address associated with your mongo server.
(Obvs, put your actual db hostname into the command, not my example.)

It's a little strange that your hosting provider didn't ask for the hostname when you didn't know the IP address. If they were *my* hosting provider, my confidence in the competence of their support would go down a notch because of that.

And please be aware that running a db in one data center and a node app (or indeed any app that uses the db) in another data center is a formula for poor performance and unreliability. The app and the db work best with a short and private network connecting them. With respect, it doesn't seem likely you have the network engineering chops to make that sort of thing stable and reliable.

Not to mention the security problems with exposing mongodb to the public network. Your hosting service is reluctant to open a port for a very good reason. [Read this](https://krebsonsecurity.com/2017/01/extortionists-wipe-thousands-of-databases-victims-who-pay-up-get-stiffed/). Because cybercreeps

Comment: Okay wait. Let me explain. My database is in Atlas. How do i access that?

Comment: It's true I'm just starting out using mongodb and node in a production environment. I don't know a whole lot of stuff. I've also seen why they are reluctant to open the port.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I was able to get the IP address of my database. I'll take your advice and really study proper security measures for my database